# I've created a custom User model. Can the CustomUserManager I create also extend django.contrib.gis.db.GeoManager?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm implementing a custom user model that looks roughly like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    id = models.IntegerField(DjangoUser, primary_key=True, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True, null=False)

    flag = models.PointField(srid=4326, geography=True, null=True)

    # objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

As a requirement, I need to continue support for queries against the flag field (which is only possible with `objects = models.GeoManager()`). I understand that with creating a new User model that extends `AbstractBaseUser`, I need to create a new UserManager extending `CustomUserManager`.

Is there any way to retain the functionality `GeoManager` provides while using a custom UserManager?

I apologize for the lack of appropriate terminology. This is my first django app. Feel free to fill in terms I could have used.

Comment: Could you please tell why do you have id = models.IntegerField(DjangoUser, primary_key=True, null=False) field?

Comment: It was an artifact of my previous version of this model. That line was a `OneToOneField` field pointing to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` which had been imported as `DjangoUser`. This was the state of the model when I realized what I need may not be doable. I was already stretching the limits of my knowledge of django and python, so here I am :P

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create CustomUserManager class inherited from GeoManager and add the required user-related functionality there:

```
class CustomUserManager(GeoManager):
    def create_user(self, ...):
        ...

class User(AbstactBaseUser):
     ...
     objects = CustomUserManager()
```